# How to calculate execute time of a goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

At this example https://play.golang.org/p/qDCZQUUhw6 I don't understand why goroutine at line 22 finished before goroutine at line 21? Please explain. 
Many thanks.

Comment: You're more likely to get answers if you include the relevant parts of code in your question directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need

```
go sum(s[:len(s)/2], c)
x := <- c
go sum(s[len(s)/2:], c)
y := <- c
```

I guest that you're using the same channel.

Comment: Have you tried that code? I just tried but the goroutine 2 `go sum(s[len(s)/2:], c)` always finished before the firsth goroutine  `go sum(s[:len(s)/2], c)`

Answer (score 0):

The order of execution of goroutines is not guaranteed.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/concurrency-golang-uttam-gandhi?forceNoSplash=true